# Copy and Filter out selected fields from 2 tabs in the Same Gsheet to another Tab with common category Fraud = 'Yes'

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

Copy and Filter out selected fields from 2 tabs in the Same Gsheet to another Tab with Fraud = 'Yes'

I have 2 sets Tabs in the Same Gsheet with different information. I would like to copy them into another tab with Fraud ="Yes". I have an example with formulas in Combine Example from Stall A Example and Stall B Example with some help previously. When I tried to replicated into my actual data (Combine NSU and ACH ) set I can't do it.

Can someone please help and guide on this.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N35wUB-a7hDHFTzdhajlaCTJf_Ce34Ql3Miwq51JCqY/edit?usp=sharing

Whenever it is Fraud = "Yes", it extracts the necessary information from NSU Tab and ACH Tab with has Fraud = Yes into Combine NSU and ACH Tab

```
#=SORT(
 LAMBDA(DATA,
  LAMBDA(DATE,TYPE,AMOUNT,FRAUD,ID,ERP
FILTER({TEXT(DATE,"dd/mm/yyyy"),TYPE,AMOUNT,FRAUD,ID,ERP},FRAUD="YES")
  )(INDEX(DATA,,1),INDEX(DATA,,2),INDEX(DATA,,8),INDEX(DATA,,13),INDEX(DATA,,15),INDEX(DATA,,16))
 )({'NSU'!A2:P27;{'ACH'!A2:A8, 'ACH'!B2:B8,'ACH'!N2:N8,'ACH'!L2:L8,'ACH'!F2:F8,'ACH'!H2:H8 }})
,1,TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

[image]

Output:

[image]

1. Get all data of sheet NSU and ASH, and re-arrange their orders by QUERY.
2. Group them up with another QUERY to filter the data you want such as Col4 = 'Yes'.
3. All the formating and sort can also be done with query.

```
=ArrayFormula(
 LAMBDA(NSU,ACH,
  QUERY({NSU;ACH},
   " WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL "
  &" AND Col4 = 'Yes' "
  &" ORDER BY Col1 ASC"
  &" LABEL Col1 'Date',Col2 'Type',Col3 'Amount',Col4 'Fraud',Col5 'ID',Col6 'ERP' "
  &" FORMAT Col1 'yyyy-mm-dd' "
  )
 )(
  LAMBDA(COLS,
   QUERY({NSU!$A:$P},
    " SELECT "&JOIN(",","Col"&COLS)
   &" LABEL "&JOIN(",","Col"&COLS&" '"&REPT(" ",COLS)&"'"),1)
  )({1,2,8,13,15,16}),
  LAMBDA(COLS,
   QUERY({ACH!$A:$N},
    " SELECT "&JOIN(",","Col"&COLS)
   &" LABEL "&JOIN(",","Col"&COLS&" '"&REPT(" ",COLS)&"'"),1)
  )({1,2,14,12,6,8})
 )
)
```

Well, in-case you really want to have the ability to add some input fields in-between the output QUERY.

The answer is you can't, but also you can.

Basically, you cannot insert anything in-between any kind of array outputs in google spreadsheets, the array-formula will return an error '#ref' mentioning that there are other values inside the output range which fail it from showing the output, BUT...

you can always get around this issue by simply seperate the output array by an other QUERY, such as:

This simple array in google sheet will reference range A1:C10 and place the data into where-ever you type this formula into, which output a 10 rows by 3 columns array.

```
={A1:C10}
```

We assumne that you put this in cell 'E1', that makes the output covers range 'E1:G10'.

[image: E1]

If you what to have a column of fields which allow you to input new data in-between the output range, for example, you want to add a new column in F:F.

In that case, you can put 2 formula seperatly into cell 'E1' and cell 'G1', which contains the following formulas:

1. in cell 'E1':

```
=QUERY({A1:C10},"SELECT Col1")
```

[image: E1]

2. in cell 'G1':

```
=QUERY({A1:C10},"SELECT Col2,Col3")
```

[image: G1]

Since the output arrays are seperated, that makes the column(s) between the column E and column G a normal empty column, which allows you to input anything into the cells.

[image: F1]

The beauty of QUERY function is that you can select any column(s) of a given reference array as an output.

In this case the output data will be seperated into 2 parts, one contains only the first column of the reference, the second one contains the rest of them.

It doesn't matter how many empty columns you insert between the 2 outputs since they are 2 outputs of one identical reference.

The draw back is, if your reference data are results of calculations, the sheet will have to do all those calculations two times, even if they gives the same results, which is why I say this can and will slow things down and are not very recommended.

Comment: you are awesome! How can I ask you more questions?

Comment: @MelLee I have added some additional information to explain about how to add input fields in-between an output array, see if you get the point or not.